# Why does a "200 OK" jQuery GET request return an empty string when reading Tumblr "Liked" posts using Basic Auth?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, tumblr

...when I can access the data using the direct URL » http://www.tumblr.com/api/likes?email=myemail@gmail.com&password=mypassword&debug=1, which gives me the posts I'm looking for:

```
Array
(
    [posts] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1482002179
                    [url] => http://staff.tumblr.com/post/1482002179
                    [url-with-slug] => http://staff.tumblr.com/post/1482002179/the-new-dashboard-for-iphone
                    [type] => photo
                    [date-gmt] => 2010-11-04 21:19:33 GMT
                    [date] => Thu, 04 Nov 2010 17:19:33
                    [bookmarklet] => 0
                    [mobile] => 0
                    [feed-item] => 
                    [from-feed-id] => 0
                    [unix-timestamp] => 1288905573
                    [format] => html
                    [reblog-key] => 8LVzAqTT
                    [slug] => the-new-dashboard-for-iphone
                    [liked] => 1
                    [note-count] => 2378
                    [tumblelog] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Tumblr Staff
                            [name] => staff
                            [cname] => 
                            [url] => http://staff.tumblr.com/
                            [timezone] => US/Eastern
                            [avatar_url_16] => http://28.media.tumblr.com/avatar_013241641371_16.png
                            [avatar_url_24] => http://26.media.tumblr.com/avatar_013241641371_24.png
```

... and so on.

But no such luck when I try to achieve the same using jQuery code where I'm using this GET request with [authenticated read as noted in the Tumblr REST API docs](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api#api_likes):

```
   $.GET(
     "http://www.tumblr.com/api/likes", 
     { email: "myemail@gmail.com", password: "mypassword" }
   );
```

I'm monitoring responses using Firebug. Status: 200 OK. Response: *empty*. XML: *no element found*.

Tracing out the response using:

```
   $.GET(
     "http://www.tumblr.com/api/likes", 
     { email: "myemail@gmail.com", password: "mypassword" },
     function( data ){ 
        alert( data ); 
     }
   );
```

displays an *empty* alert message.

I get the same result no matter where I run the code from be it file:///, localhost( XAMPP ), my own server or right from within my theme on mysite.tumblr.com.

Am I missing something? I could achieve this with JavaScript + PHP, cURL etc but I'm looking for JavaScript-only solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're running into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You can't use Ajax to load data from just anywhere, you're limited to loading data from the same *origin* as the original document (not the script, the HTML document).

Assuming that's the problem, then:

If both the browser and remote site support [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) and your origin is acceptable to the remote site, you can use that. But note that right now, only some browsers support it (and IE only supports it if you make a [special effort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28VS.85%29.aspx), whereas other browsers support it as part of their `XmlHTTPRequest` object support, which is what jQuery's `get` uses under the covers).

You can probably use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) if tumblr supports it, though, which jQuery has support for in its [`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) call (not `.GET` as in your code examples).

Another option is to use [Yahoo! Query Language as a cross-domain proxy](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax).

Comment: Tumblr has JSON support but weirdly( my guess being that it was a recent addition and they are still working on it ) their Liked posts / dashboard api doesn't. It's on users' wishlists[ http://codelahoma.com/post/697228236/whats-missing-from-the-tumblr-api-part-1 ]though. I guess using a proxy is the only option left to us then.

Comment: To save time I've stopped fiddling around and gone the proxy route. Not very elegant but it works.

Comment: @vjk2005 they do have JSON support on dashboard, but it's undocumented. Default they give you XML, but if you hit `api/dashboard/json` instead it works...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your getting a 200? perhaps try this to be sure the response should = "success" if everything went ok - as far as I am aware the callback function gets called regardless of the outcome.

```
$.GET(
 "http://www.tumblr.com/api/likes", 
 { email: "myemail@gmail.com", password: "mypassword" },
 function( data, response ){ 
    alert( response ); 
 }
```

);

Maybe it's something simple like a / at the end of you're URL

I typically do ajax posts like this

```
$.post(
 "http://www.tumblr.com/api/likes", 
 { email: "myemail@gmail.com", password: "mypassword" },
 function( data, response ){
    if(response == "success")
    {
        //inject data into page
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Ooops something went wrong... please try again.");
    }

 }
```

);

And the documentation for $.get states that:

If a request with jQuery.get() returns an error code, it will fail silently unless the script has also called the global .ajaxError() method.

Comment: I tried adding a slash at the end of the URL but it returned a 403. Even $.post returns a 403. I haven't tried checking for the "success" response and that's my next move before going the proxy route.